# Find an element in a JSON file and show it in HTML

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON file

```
{
    "agenti":[
    {"codice":"3425", "nome":"fabrizio", "cognome":"mazzeini", "azienda":"kra", "indirizzo": {"via":"via milano", "citta":"Roma","stato":"Italia"}},
    {"codice":"3476", "nome":"marco", "cognome":"sormani", "azienda":"bertucci", "indirizzo": {"via":"via Siena", "citta":"Milano" , "stato":"Italia"}},
    {"codice":"4525", "nome":"francesco", "cognome":"stefanucci", "azienda":"ovs", "indirizzo": {"via":"via italia", "citta":"Milano" , "stato":"Italia"}},
    {"codice":"3405", "nome":"emilio", "cognome":"emiglietti", "azienda":"paoletti", "indirizzo": {"via":"via delle forze armate", "citta":"Milano" , "stato":"Italia"}},
    {"codice":"3915", "nome":"gianni", "cognome":"sperti", "azienda":"giacomazzi", "indirizzo": {"via":"via quarenghi", "citta":"Milano" , "stato":"Italia"}},
 {"codice":"3429", "nome":"franca", "cognome":"solari", "azienda":"apple", "indirizzo": {"via":"via dei missaglia", "citta":"Milano" , "stato":"Italia"}}
]}
```

And the following HTML/JS file

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>JSON</h1>
    <button id="es" type="button" onclick="testJSON()"> UPLOAD JSON </button>
    Search for agenti per <br> <br>
    Nome<input type="text" id="nome"> <br><br>
    <button type="button" id="filtra" onclick="filter()"> Filter </button>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
    <script>
var agenti = "";
    function testJSON() 
    {
      var successo = function(result) {
      console.log("success");
      console.log(result);
      agenti = result;
    };
    var error = function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    };
    $.ajax ({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "agenti.json",
      success: successo,
      error: error
    });
    var a = 10; 
  }
    </script>
    <script>
    function filter() {
      var name = document.getElementById("nome").value;
for (var i=0; i < agenti.length; i++) {
  if (agenti[i].nome === nome) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = name;
  }
}
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I fill the input box with "fabrizio" for example... But HTML does not return any value and does not print "fabrizio" as a found element in the JSON file...
But if i do something like that:

```
 <script>
var name = document.getElementById("nome").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = name;
    function filter() {
for (var i=0; i < agenti.length; i++) {
  if (agenti[i].nome === nome) {

  }
}
}
</script>
```

and i fill in the input box with a casual name, HTML returns the name in the document (and prints it) even if is not present in the JSON file

I guess the problem is in the for loop and precisely in the if conditional

What can i do ? Thanks to everybody

Answer (score 2):

you have :

```
agenti = result;
```

so within that data structure you must go to :

```
agenti.agenti[0].nome
```

to get your result.  agenti is set to the entire encapsulating object and you want the first object, agenti, within that.  I would obviously change your variable to something less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes there. First of all mixing up JSON object keys with Javascript variables which apparently led to confusion. Also, like Mark pointed out, you have wrapped the result in the variable `agenti`. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otzbeyLf/) where all things are working. If you have more questions feel free to comment. What you do is basically:

```
var name = document.getElementById("nome").value;
for (var i = 0; i < agenti.agenti.length; i++) {
    if (agenti.agenti[i].nome === name) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = agenti.agenti[i].nome + ' & ' + agenti.agenti[i].codice;
    }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

The variable "nome" is not declared, "name" is.

```
if (agenti[i].nome === name) {}
```

"nome" is a typo you made in the JSON file and the HTML DOM, I guess. You should correct that.

Also, you don't have to create two script tags for two functions. Just put both of them into the first script tag.

Comment: I did like this

 var nome = "";
      var name = document.getElementById("nome").value;
for (var i=0; i < agenti.length; i++) {
  if (agenti[i].nome === name) {
    document.getElementById("risultato").innerHTML = name;
  }
}

but it still does not work

Comment: The above answer is correct, you should check it out (although maybe you will need both answers).